# How to properly import Python classes in IPython?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have an [IPython notebook](https://github.com/fdrollig/model-2018-12/blob/master/Model.ipynb). At the beginning, I defined all classes in the notebook itself. After a while, they became too numerous and I decided to put them into separate files, incl. [Inventory.py](https://github.com/fdrollig/model-2018-12/blob/master/Inventory.py) and [Location.py](https://github.com/fdrollig/model-2018-12/blob/master/Location.py).

`Location` creates an instance of `Inventory` in its constructor:

```
from Inventory import Inventory

class Location:
    [...]
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.objects = []
        self.name = name
        self.accounts = []
    self.inventory = Inventory()
```

When I try create an instance of `Location` inside the IPython notebook, I get the following error:

[image: Screenshot]

What do I need to change in my code in order to get rid of this error? Why is the import statement (`from Inventory import Inventory`) not sufficient to import `Invetory` in `Location`?

Comment: Did you edit `Location.py` without restarting your notebook? You need to restart it.

Comment: Best practice - name your modules `snake_case` and name your classes `ProperCase`. I'd expect to see `from inventory import Inventory`.